# Automapping issue

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper

I am new to AutoMapper ✌ and struggling with the mapping of an array with values to a Entity Framework model.
It should be very simple but I get the exception for several hours right now.. (Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping)

I just created a class automapper configuration class:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Response<Car>, Car>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.Brand, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Content.Values.Where(p => p.Code == "brand").FirstOrDefault().Content))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.Color, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Content.Values.Where(p => p.Code == "color").FirstOrDefault().Content))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.BuildYear, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Content.Values.Where(p => p.Code == "buildyear").FirstOrDefault().Content))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Content.Values.Where(p => p.Code == "price").FirstOrDefault().Content));
    }
}
```

}

And I call this in my startup class..

```
AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

And this where the mapping should happen. (In a hangfire job)

```
Mapper.Map<Car>(response.Content.Values));
```

Is seems that the mapping configuration is unsupported, are there any alternatives to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the type of `response.Content.Values` ?

Comment: Values is a collection of Value[] which is a XML serialization class (string code and string content)

Comment: If I understand correctly your configuration is a mapping of the entire response object, in that case it should suffice to use `Mapper.Map<Car>(response);` ?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! 

Comment: No problem, glad it works :)

Comment: @LennartStoop please write the answer as mentioned in comment, so this can be marked for solved